# Why am I not able to access a public member when inheriting?

Tags: c++, inheritance

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class BaseClass
{
private:
    int privateInt;
protected:
    int protectedInt;
public:
    int publicInt;
};

class ChildClass : public BaseClass
{
    publicInt = 0;
};

int main()
{
    ChildClass c;
    cout << c.publicInt;
}
```

As you can see, `ChildClass` is inheriting from `BaseClass`. `publicInt` is a public member of `BaseClass`. So why do I get an error when I try to assign a value to `publicInt` in `ChildClass`, and also when trying to print the value in main?

Comment: Because you can only write code in functions, not in class declarations. `publicInt = 0;` is not a class member or method declaration. This has nothing to do with inheritance.

Comment: When you post a question. Don't say that you get "an error". Post the exact error message.

Comment: Voted to reopen. This is not a mere typo; it's a misunderstanding of how members can be initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assignment is simply misplaced. Instead of trying to assign a value to `publicInt` in the class definition (where you should only put member declarations or type aliases), you can do so e.g. in the constructor of `ChildClass` (or any other member function):

```
class ChildClass : public BaseClass
{
  public:
    ChildClass() {
        publicInt = 0;
    }
};
```

This resolves the compiler error for the `cout` statement, too.